# Facebook SDK MVC3 - Lost canvas session

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have problems with Facebook SDK for MVC3 [1]: http://docs.csharpsdk.org/

I have lost session and current context every time make postback. I need Help please!

> ### CODE

```
            public class OverviewController :Controller
                {
                    public readonly FacebookClient _fb;
                    public readonly IMyFacebookCanvasContext _fbCanvasContext;
                    private readonly string[] ExtendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "publish_stream", "read_stream" };

         public OverviewController(FacebookClient fb, IMyFacebookCanvasContext fbCanvasContext)
                {
                        _fb = fb;
                        _fbCanvasContext = fbCanvasContext;
                }

public ActionResult Index()
        { 
       dynamic result = _fb.Get("me", new { fields = new[] { "name", "picture" } 

       return View();
        }
    }
```

I`m used this example [1]: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-mvc

Comment: What type of session are you running on your server?  Also what's the value of your p3p header?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the signed_request manually for postbacks and ajax requests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5364815/157260

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
}
```